# while in python has no sense

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have no idea what's happening there.
It's something so simple, but I've been experimenting for long and it's have no sense.

Here is the code:

```
var = int( input( 'Select "2" o "3" (Write your answer). ' ))
while var != 1 & var != 2:
    var = int (input( 'Invalid. You have to write "2" or "3". ' ))

print('You select', var)
```

If I answer the input *with 1*, it works, as is suposed to do. But when i answer *2, it enter in the loop*.
And **the strangest part** is that when i Write *0 it don't enter in the loop*!

> Someone has and idea of what can be happening. **Maybe is an
>   interpreter problem...**

It's only a reduction of my problem, but I can't use the while loop by this way!!

Answer (score 3):

`&` and `and` are not the same operator in Python.

- `and` means [*logical (aka boolean) and*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), the one you want—it's truthy if both of its arguments are truthy.
- `&` means [*bitwise and*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations)—it returns a new number with `1` for every bit that was `1` in both arguments (e.g., `5 & 3`, aka `0b101 & 0b011`, is `1`, aka `0b001`, and `6 & 1` is `0`—which is false, even though both arguments are true, because they don't share any bits in common). That's not what you want.

On top of that, they have different [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) (notice that `and` comes above `!=` in the table, but `&` comes below it), so what you're actually doing is `var != (1 & var) != 2`. Since `1 != 2`, this is true no matter what `1 & var` happens to be.

---

There are two more differences that aren't relevant here, but worth learning:

- `x and y` short-circuits: if `x` is false, Python doesn't evaluate `y`. This means you can do things like `if x and x.spam()`, and know it won't call `None.spam()` and raise an exception if `x` is `None`. But `&` is just a normal operator, like `+`, that always evaluates both arguments.
- `x and y` always compares the values as boolean truthy-or-falsey; it can't be overriden by custom classes to do custom things, but `x & y` can—e.g., it means set intersection if the values are sets, or elementwise bitwise and if they're numpy arrays, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've no idea of the difference.
I can't find one utility for the bitwise...

Comment: @LisandroDallaCosta One common use for bitwise operations is for flags: `x&1, x&2, x&4, x&8, x&16, …` are all independent of each other, so you can store dozens of flags in a single small integer. That doesn't come up nearly as often in Python as in, say, C—and if you don't think you have a use for it, don't go out of your way looking for one; just don't use it. But if you ever need it, it's there.